# RSA calculating e in C#

Tags: c#

I would like the have a second opinion on my code I've written to calculate `e`

`e` is an integer that you wherefore the following counts `gcd(φ(n),e) = 1 with 1 < e < φ(n)`

```
public int calce()
{
    do
    {
        e = priemgen.newKey(1, euler);
    } while (GCD(euler, e) != 1);  

    return e;
}

private int GCD(int value1, int value2)
{
    while (value1 != 0 && value2 != 0)
    {
        if (value1 > value2)
        {
            value1 %= value2;
        }
        else
            value2 %= value1;
    }

    return Math.Max(value1, value2);
}

private int NewPrime(int lowerbound, int upperbound)
{
    return priemgen.newKey(lowerbound, upperbound);
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify this sentence please: `e is an integer that you wherefore the following counts`? I have trouble understanding what it should mean.

Comment: 1) I'd fix `e to a small prime (3 or 65537) and reject the primes if `e` dives `p-1`. 2) Why `int` instead of `BigInteger`?

Comment: Just to be clear: if this is for anything other than learning/school, you should NOT be implementing RSA in C#. Instead use the prebuilt C# classes in System.Security.Cryptography which will do all of the encryption properly and securely.

Answer (score 5):

There is not a huge amount of code to review here, just a few things:

1. You have a method `NewPrime` which I assume provides a prime number between the two bounds provided. Yet you do not use it and call `priemgen.newKey` directly in `calce`. You should either get rid of the wrapper method or use it consistently.
2. Braces are used inconsistently:

   ```
   else
       value2 %= value1;
   ```

   Should be same as the if block:

   ```
   else
   {
       value2 %= value1;
   }
   ```
3. The naming conventions are inconsistent. Standard naming convention for C# for methods and fields is `PascalCase` and local variables and parameters are `camelCase`:

   - `calce` -> `CalculateE`
   - `newKey` on `priemgen` should be `NewKey`
   - `priemgen` - I assume it's a field so should be `PrimGenerator`
   - `lowerbound` -> `lowerBound`
   - `upperbound` -> `upperBound`
   - `GCD` -> `Gcd`
4. If `priemgen` is what it sounds like then the name for `nextKey` should be `NextPrime`.
5. What does `priemgen.newKey` return if there is no prime within the given bounds?